# My program has repetitions of similar code that I would like to eliminate

Tags: python, variables, names

My code has several variables whose names differ by only one character. It the same code repeated several times once for each 'version' of the variable. I would like to have a single piece of code that can do these operations on all of the 'versions' of the variable.

I have not managed to find a solution for this that works.

```
if sType_A == sBirth_F:
    sOriginalDate =  tbBDate.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    tbBDate.config( state= "normal" )
    tbBDate.delete("1.0","end")
    sDate_G = getVerifiedDate( sOriginalDate )
    tbBDate.insert( '1.0', sDate_G )
    tbBDate.config( state= "disabled" )
    svBDate.set( sDate_G )
if sType_A == "Marriage":
    sOriginalDate =  tbMDate.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    tbMDate.config( state= "normal" )
    tbMDate.delete("1.0","end")
    sDate_G = getVerifiedDate( sOriginalDate )
    tbMDate.insert( '1.0', sDate_G )
    tbMDate.config( state= "disabled" )
    svMDate.set( sDate_G )
if sType_A == "Location":
    sOriginalDate =  tbLDate.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    tbLDate.config( state= "normal" )
    tbLDate.delete("1.0","end")
    sDate_G = getVerifiedDate( sOriginalDate )
    tbLDate.insert( '1.0', sDate_G )
    tbLDate.config( state= "disabled" )
    svLDate.set( sDate_G )
if sType_A == "Occupation":
    sOriginalDate =  tbODate.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    tbODate.config( state= "normal" )
    tbODate.delete("1.0","end")
    sDate_G = getVerifiedDate( sOriginalDate )
    tbODate.insert( '1.0', sDate_G )
    tbODate.config( state= "disabled" )
    svODate.set( sDate_G )
if sType_A == "Death":
    sOriginalDate =  tbDDate.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    tbDDate.config( state= "normal" )
    tbDDate.delete("1.0","end")
    sDate_G = getVerifiedDate( sOriginalDate )
    tbDDate.insert( '1.0', sDate_G )
    tbDDate.config( state= "disabled" )
    svDDate.set( sDate_G )
```

Comment: I think this might suite better to [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It might be worth adjusting your variable names to be more clear, it took me a few read-throughs before I noticed the differences in `tbMDate`, `tbDDate`, `tbODate`, etc

Comment: if you post on Code Review please read the help center pages like [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - in its current form this post would be considered off-topic because there is little context about what the code does and how the function is used, plus the title is about CR goals instead of describing what the code does

Comment: The code is used to date textboxes for an app to allow the user to update a family tree. The letters which differentiate the variables represent Birth, Marriage, Occupation, Location and Death.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dictionary of the different possible variables:

```py
types = {
    sBirth_F: (tbBDate, svBDate),
    "Marriage": (tbMDate, svMDate),
    "Occupation": (tbODate, svODate),
    "Location": (tbLDate, svLDate),
    "Death": (tbBDate, svDDate)
}

if sType_A in types.keys():
    tbDate, svDate = types[sType_A]
    sOriginalDate = tbDate.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    tbDate.config(state="normal")
    tbDate.delete("1.0", "end")
    sDate_G = getVerifiedDate(sOriginalDate)
    tbDate.insert('1.0', sDate_G)
    tbDate.config(state="disabled")
    svDate.set(sDate_G)
```

If it weren't for the odd `sBirth_F`, this could be shortened using `globals()`, but alas.

Comment: Thanks for this B Remmelzwaal. It does exactly what I wanted. Most appreciated.